# how to sort trimmed values in hash map

Tags: java, android

I'm having trouble sorting trimmed values in my hash map after parsing json string.

```
//Read data
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
       result.append(line);
       }

JSONObject jsonObjectResult = new JSONObject(result.toString().trim());
JSONArray jsonArrayApps = jsonObjectResult.getJSONArray("apps");
try
{
    for (int i=0; i<jsonArrayApps.length(); i++)
     {
         HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
         JSONObject e = jsonArrayApps.getJSONObject(i);
         map.put("Name", e.getString("package").trim() );
         map.put("cate", e.getString("category").trim());
         mylist.add(map);  //mylist is a variable for a listview
     }
}
catch (JSONException e)
{
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}
```

the following are the results

[list of installed apps and their categories (Click to view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW7ZT.png)

I need help in sorting out the trimmed values so that the sorted data can be in their own categories.  [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJhZn.png)

here is my json code

```
public class now extends AsyncTask <HttpURLConnection, Void,Void>
{
    private void getAppCategories() throws IOException, JSONException
    {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        //Create JSON object to send to webservice
        JSONObject jsonObjectSend = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jsonArrayPakages = new JSONArray();
        PackageManager packageManager;
        List<ResolveInfo> listApps; //this list store all app in device

        try
        {
            packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
            Intent filterApp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            filterApp.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            listApps = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(filterApp,    PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

            for (ResolveInfo app : listApps)
            {
            jsonArrayPakages.put(app.activityInfo.packageName.trim());
            }

            jsonObjectSend.put("packages", jsonArrayPakages);

            Log.d("json", jsonObjectSend.toString());

            URL url = new URL("http://getdatafor.appspot.com/data?key=53972606b926d38191a5446fdff89e377873d767fabedf6d");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(30000); /* milliseconds */
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(30000); /* milliseconds */
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application-json");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true); /* allow output to send data */
            urlConnection.connect();

            OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            bufferedWriter =  new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
            bufferedWriter.write(jsonObjectSend.toString());
            bufferedWriter.flush();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            //continues from (//read line)
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(HttpURLConnection... params) {
    try {
            getAppCategories();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("tag", "Net work error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("tag", "JSON is not valid:  " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;
}
```

Comment: do you have fixed number of category list ?

Comment: no i don't @patel  .. it fetches the categories online ...

Comment: @vitus can you please share your json format, you want to just show each app under it's categories instead of under un-category list right ?

Comment: yes... alright i'm on it @Vayalu

Comment: Hash maps are not sorted. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: i've added the full json format

Comment: @EJP the uploaded code returns results like this  com.nikki.vector ---- Racing         and this is added to a hashmap to store the trimmed result. i need to sort this trimmed values such that those with unknown categories goes to another list and those with category Racing goes to another list..

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<jsonArrayApps.length(); i++)
     {
         HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
         JSONObject e = jsonArrayApps.getJSONObject(i);
         map.put("Name", e.getString("package").trim() );
         map.put("cate", e.getString("category").trim());
         mylist.add(map);  //mylist is a variable for a listview
     }
```

Here you are making HashMap for each item. But what you need to do is just first check HashMap to category already added if yes, then added in existing list otherwise create new list.

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> mylist = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
for (int i=0; i<jsonArrayApps.length(); i++)
     {
         JSONObject e = jsonArrayApps.getJSONObject(i);
         String appName = e.getString("package").trim();
         String category = e.getString("category").trim();
         List<String> appList = mylist.get(category);
         if(appList == null) {
            appList = new ArrayList<String>();
            //Add category if not exist
            mylist.put(category, appList);
         }
         appList.add(appName);
     }
```

Btw, you also need to bit tweak inside your ListView Adapter class though (i think).

Comment: pls elaborate @Vayalu.. Thanks for the reply

Comment: I've tried everything I think I know@Vayalu yet I get errors when I declare this    HashMap<String, List<String>> mylist = new HashMap(<String>, List<String>);

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: @vitus if you feel answer is correct or helped a lot to fix issue or implement stuff then please mark it as a correct answer. Feel free to ask if you have any issue.